# Why do API implementers avoid cookie use outside of browsers?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, cookies

A lot of APIs use token auth for authentication and authorization. I thought the original use of token auth schemes were that cookies were intended for browsers and that you could not guarantee that your API consumer would be a browser.

But then when you think about, cookies are almost exactly the same as many token auth schemes that people invent, except that cookies are supported and understood by every web framework out there and have most of the features of token auth, such as expiration dates. Cookies just have a "Cookie:" and "Set-Cookie:" header instead of the usual X-Auth-Token. Why do so many API implementers go out of their way to re-invent the wheel?

Why not make API clients conform to cookie usage (since they will have to learn your token auth scheme anyway)?

Comment: I think that's because [1] many people don't like cookies (safety problems) and [2] not using cookies allow you to develop apps that don't have to emulate a browser to manage cookies